# Parent Component Reverting to Initial State After Updating State w/ Callback in Child

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am sending a callback function from a parent to a child component, and although the parent successfully updates it's state based on input provided to the child, it immediately reverts back to initial state, thus resulting in the browser briefly flashing the input that was provided and then displaying the initial state. What is the fix for this? Here is my code:

Parent:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
     this.state = { item: '' }
     this.getItem=this.getItem.bind(this);
  }

  getItem(val) {
    this.setState({
      item: val
    })
    console.log(this.state.item);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Input getItem={this.getItem} />
      <h2>{this.state.item}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Child:

```
class Input extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { value: '' }
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    })
    console.log(this.state.value)
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    {this.props.getItem(this.state.value)};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            <input type="text" name={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="+" />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by using `e.preventDefault()` in the handleSubmit function.